# Power BI DAX Formula DISTINCT not respecting the current filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax

To simply explain my question I created this super simple set of data:

- A date table called 'dDates' with all the dates of 2021;
- A fact table called 'fSales' containing 3 products sold in 2021 with the respective sale date;
- A one to many relationship between my date table and my fact table.

The scheme can be seen below.

[image]

Then to first check If the filtering from the date table is being correctly propagated to the fact table, I went to the canvas and:

- Added a slicer with the 'Date' column of the 'dDates' table;
- Created a new measure called 'Rows Visible' to just count the rows visible at the 'fSales' table with the formula: COUNTROWS('fSales').

The result is as expected as shown below. That means, If I chance the slicer selection, the COUNTROWS formula returns 1, 2 or 3 (i.e. the number of rows visible af the 'fSales' table).

[image]

Moving forward, I need now to create a virtual table in DAX and my starting point is to get a column with the distinc products sold that are visible at the 'fSales' table.

The virtual table creation formula is: Distinc Products Sold = DISTINCT(fSales[Product Sold])

You can see the result at the image below.

The problem is that It seems that the DISTINCT formula is not respecting the current filter context. What I mean by that is that no matter the selection on the dates at the slicer, always the three products are being shown at the virtual table.

For example, If the slicer dates selection is from January 2021 to March 2021 that means that only 1 row is visible at the fSales table, and therefore the DISTINC of this column should return only 1 product.

What am I missing? Where is the issue that I'm not seing?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why you do need a distunct table when it is working on the table you have by default? Other question, did you make a relation between the 2 tables on product?

Comment: Hi Aldert. The default fact table has hundreds of thousands of lines, but I just want to make the analysts on the products that were sold on a given date. The only relation between the tables is the one to many relationships between the dates.

Comment: Calculated tables and columns are static data; they can not respond to the changes in the filter context. The fact that you used DAX to generate the table is irrelevant - after the table is calculated, it's added to the data model as static data, no different from imported data. To solve the problem, don't create a virtual table, create a DAX measure instead.

Comment: If you just put the Product Sold from fSales, you will get the distinct list in relationship to the slicers. You don't need to create a separate distinct table. The rest is as @RADO mentioned.